# Mount a partition from a VM disk ZFS snapshot in FreeNAS

Tags: linux, freebsd, zfs, mount, truenas

I have a KVM image running on a Zvol in linux that is a block device containing an ext4 partition. It is snapshotted regularly and pushed to a FreeNAS box for backup. If I ever need to recover a single file from one of these snapshots, in Linux I'm able to zfs clone the snapshot, which creates a device node in /dev/zvol for both the block device and the partition, which I can successfully mount.

In FreeNAS, however, I only see a device node for the block device. If I run fdisk on it, I can see the partition, but I can't find a way to mount it.

```
zfs clone backups/txa/data/vm-400-disk-1@2018-07-30:10:56:15 backups/txa/test-400
fdisk /dev/zvol/backups/txa/test-400

The data for partition 1 is:
sysid 131 (0x83),(Linux native)
start 2048, size 314572800 (153600 Meg), flag 80 (active)
    beg: cyl 0/ head 32/ sector 33;
    end: cyl 1023/ head 254/ sector 63
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On VM of FreeNAS install any linux distro and map this volume to this VM as additional map point recover your files in general way when this point is mounted.